# Testing $http.post method in karma jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

i have a function in my controller as below:

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

define(['angular', 'app/controllers'], function (angular, controllers) {
    console.log("Loading controller:");

    controllers.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $timeout, $log, $location, $route, $routeParams, $http) {

    $scope.saveWorkflowTRIGGERS = function(saveCall) {
        var url = BASE_APP_PATH + "trigger/save";

        $http.post(url, $scope.triggers).success(function(data) {

            console.log("savedTriggers");
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
  });
  });
```

How do i unit test this so that the post method is mocked and invoked. Currently i have the below which does not cover the success part for the post call.

```
define(['angular-mocks', 'jquery', 'app/app'], function(angularmocks, $, app){
describe('Unit: Testing Controller', function(){
    var ctrl;
    var scope;
var rootScope;
var mockHttp;

BASE_APP_PATH='some path/';

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $window, $httpBackend){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    rootScope = $rootScope;

    mockHttp = $httpBackend;

}));

it ('should save triggers', function(){

    inject(function ($controller) {
        ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });

        var url = BASE_APP_PATH + 'trigger/save';

        mockHttp.whenPOST(url, 'mockData').respond(201, 'success');
        mockHttp.expectPOST(url).respond(201, 'success');
        scope.save(true); 
        mockHttp.flush();
    });
});

});
});
```

Comment: You would need to call [`$httpBackend.flush()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) to flush pending requests once the method under test is called.

Comment: Edited the original with flush. but getting exception "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: I don't know how the test case is written by only looking at the portion of it. Can you all the full test case and the controller, is feasible?

Comment: Edited the qs with the controller and the full test case.

Answer (score 0):

In a first look, it seems you're calling a save function and your function is called `saveWorkflowTRIGGERS`. I think that's why you're getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

You should have `scope.$digest()` after the save call which will resolve the pending http call.